# How can I get step jump in for loop when it has a while conditioned on the for loop's variable

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, matrix, while-loop

My matrix is a 8x8 having binary values. I want to filter out patterns of consecutive three 1's i.e.(111) in the diagonals of upper triangular matrix of M. I have written a piece of python code with for and while loop but it did not work and I am unable to figure out whats happening there. Please help..

```
rf =([1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0],
     [1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0],
     [1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0],
     [1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0],
     [1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0],
     [1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0],
     [1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0],
     [1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0])

for i in range(1):
    for j in range(len (rf)-3):
        while (i<len(rf)-3 and j<len(rf)-3):
             count =0
             if rf[i,j]==True:     
               for w in range(3):
                   if rf[i+w,j+w]==True:
                      count +=1
                      print count
               if count==3:
                  i=i+3
                  j=j+3
               else:
                    rf[i,j]=False
                    i=i+1
                    j=j+1
```

Comment: What's the point of `for i in range(1)`? You may just as well drop the loop and assign `i = 0`.

Comment: What do you mean by "filter out" here? Do you want to reset those three 1s to 0s or do you want to know where they occur?

Comment: Two things - you don't have a 8x8 matrix unless there is an error in copy paste; and be careful with numbers that start with 0, as this is the octal notation in Python 2.

Comment: I want to retain three consecutive 1's if number of 1's are >=3 otherwise make them 0. And the window length (3 in this case) is a variable in general.

Comment: It is not a 8x8 matrix here

Comment: In the sample matrix, there's not a single occurrance of three consecutive ones in a diagonal, right?

Comment: Sorry, now it is 8x8 matrix. thank you for pointing out the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might simplify your code using `numpy` to access diagonals:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> rf = [[1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0]] * 8
>>> m = np.array(rf)
>>> m.diagonal(0)
array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0])
>>> m.diagonal(1)
array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0])
```

a simply routine to find positions of consecutive ones:

```
def consecutive_values(arr, val=1, cnt=3):
    def comparator(pos):
        return arr[pos] == val
    if len < cnt:
        return []
    else:
        return [p for p, x in  enumerate(arr[:1-cnt]) 
                     if all(map(comparator, xrange(p, p+cnt, 1)))]
```

and usage:

```
>>> consecutive_values([1]*5)
[0, 1, 2]

>>> consecutive_values([1]*5 + [0]*4 + [1]*3)
[0, 1, 2, 9]

>>> m = np.array([[1]*8]*8)
>>> diagonals = map(m.diagonal, range(len(m)))
>>> map(consecutive_values, diagonals)
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1], [0], [], []]
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried the diagonal idea but I gave up after struggling for a day.

Comment: Dear Frerich, yes, that is true and that's what I want that if there is no 111 then fill the canvas with zeroes

Comment: @user2964728 what is canvas? and see update for simple consecutive values extractor

Comment: canvas means the area in the upper triangular region when I plot this matrix in 2-D dotplot